# Increment and while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

Following is the code I'm executing in IDLE for Python 3.5.2 on Windows 10:

```
spam = 0
while spam < 5:
    print('Hello, world.')
    spam = spam + 1
```

I can see Hello World printed 5 times however when entering spam in IDLE, I can see the integer 5.
Shouldn't this be logically int 6 since while loop will stop as soon as the spam is incremented by 1 from 5 and spam variable is passed with the incremented int?

Thank you!

Comment: check your indentation of the last line.  I believe it should be part of your while loop code

Comment: As written, your while loop stops as soon as `spam` is 5, why do you think it would print 6?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`spam < 5` can be read as spam is less than 5, so it'll only increment from 0 to 4. In the 4th (last) iteration, `spam = 4` so it prints 'Hello, world' and then `spam + 1 = 5`. At that point it will attempt another iteration, but `spam < 5` is no longer true and therefore will exit the loop.

For reference: `<` means less than, `<=` means less than or equal to.

Any particular reason you think you'd get 6?

Answer (score 2):

Your while loop is "while spam is **less than** 5", not "while spam is **less than or equal** to 5". The last iteration occurs when spam is 4, and then it gets incremented one last time to 5.

If spam equals 5, it is **not** less than 5, so the while loop stops iterating.

Answer (score 0):

I added a print statement to illustrate what is happening:

```
spam = 0
while spam < 5:
    print('Hello, world.')
    spam = spam + 1
    print(spam, 'spam is < 5?', spam < 5, "\n")
```

The output is:

```
Hello, world.
1 spam is < 5? True 

Hello, world.
2 spam is < 5? True 

Hello, world.
3 spam is < 5? True 

Hello, world.
4 spam is < 5? True 

Hello, world.
5 spam is < 5? False
```